# Finding ids where all the IDs are smaller than some date

Tags: postgresql, performance, postgresql-9.3, query-performance

Considering a simple table with id-datetime field. I want to remove all records, where datetime is smaller than some constant, but keep ids which have at least one record with bigger date.

My first effort was

```sql
DELETE FROM journal
WHERE id IN (
  SELECT
        j.id
  FROM
        journal j
  WHERE NOT EXIST (SELECT * FROM journal j2 
                   WHERE j.id == j2.id AND j2.created_at >= 636742944000000000
)
```

Which worked poorly. Then I rewrote is as following

```sql
DELETE FROM journal
WHERE id IN (
  SELECT
        j.id
  FROM
        journal j
  GROUP BY id
  HAVING MAX(created_at) < 636742944000000000;
)
```

Which behaved much better.

But I still wonder what's the most performant way to do so? Maybe some vendor-specific query extensions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try this:

```sql
DELETE FROM journal
WHERE id NOT IN (
  SELECT
        j.id
  FROM
        journal j
  WHERE j.created_at >= 636742944000000000
  ORDER BY j.created_at DESC
)
```

Please make sure to create the index on `created_at` and `id`.

In additional, I think `id` in a table should be `unique`/`primary key`.

Comment: Are you sure it works as intended? I don't think `ORDER BY` actually means anything in `IN` clause.

Comment: `ORDER BY` will make `postgres` to reverse scan in index table to get the record with the `max` of `created_at`. The key point is: don't scan all records, and only scan index table.

Comment: Right. That sounds quite good. Thanks, I'l take that.

P.S. I wonder who still downvote the question. I don't think it's stupid or violates anything... That's weird.

Answer (score 0):

I think you already are doing it the best way.

```
DELETE FROM journal
 WHERE id NOT in 
  (SELECT id 
    FROM journal
    GROUP BY (id)
    HAVING MAX(created_at) >= 636742944000000000);
```

Answer (score 0):

You will probably be faster with `NOT EXISTS`:

```
DELETE FROM journal
WHERE NOT EXISTS
   (SELECT 1 FROM journal AS j
    WHERE j.id = journal.id
    AND j.created_at >= 636742944000000000);
```